# Draw a SCNShape with Fill and Outline

Tags: ios, objective-c, scenekit

I already figured how to draw a shape - e.g. a circle with SCNSHape.

Now I want to draw an outline for that shape, so I added a subnode to my circle and tried drawing an outline with the help of the even-odd-file-rule.

This does not work and creates a lot of error messages of the type "SceneKit: error, C3DSourceAccessorCopyDataToAccessor failed" in the console.

What's the best way to create a SCNShape which represens the outline of my circle?

```
UIBezierPath *strokePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
strokePath.usesEvenOddFillRule = YES;
strokePath.lineWidth = 10.0;
[strokePath addArcWithCenter: CGPointZero radius:  5.0 startAngle: 0.0 endAngle: M_PI * 2.0f clockwise: NO];
[strokePath addArcWithCenter: CGPointZero radius: 10.0 startAngle: 0.0 endAngle: M_PI * 2.0f clockwise: NO];

SCNShape *strokeShape = [SCNShape shapeWithPath: strokePath extrusionDepth: 0];
strokeShape.firstMaterial.diffuse.contents = [UIColor blueColor];
strokeShape.firstMaterial.doubleSided = YES;

SCNNode *strokeNode = [SCNNode nodeWithGeometry: strokeShape];
```

Answer (score 3):

`SCNShape` can only be used to draw closed, non self-intersecting paths. It always uses the even-odd rule and it does not support strokes.